# Proving that an $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_k^{k+1}\sin(\exp(x))dxdk$ integral converges

Tags: integration, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, improper-integrals

Well, how can I prove that the following integral converges:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_\text{k}^{\text{k}+1}\sin\left(\exp\left(x\right)\right)\space\text{d}x\space\text{dk}\tag1$$

Comment: What is your effort? What is your motivation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\mathcal{I}= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{e^k}^{e^{k+1}}\frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz\,dk=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\text{Si}(e^{k+1})-\text{Si}(e^k)\right]\,dk=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{Si}(eu)-\text{Si}(u)}{u}\,du$$
and we may invoke [Frullani's integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) to get $\mathcal{I}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Comment: Do you know a way to prove that the integral converges without evaluating it? I actually need that for the following proof (in order to interchange the order of integrals) right? $$\int_{\infty}^\infty\int_k^{k+1}\sin\left(e^x\right)dxdk\overset{x-k=t}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^1 \sin\left(e^{t+k}\right)dtdk$$
$$= \int_0^1\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin\left(e^{t+k}\right)dtdk\overset{t+k=\ln y}=\int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin y}{y}dydk=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: @Zacky: yes, the exchange of integrals is tricky in that case. Anyway, to prove that $\int_{0}^{x}\text{Si}(u)\frac{du}{u}=\frac{\pi}{2}\log(x)+O(1)$ as $x\to +\infty$ is not difficult, one may just exploit integration by parts.