# Let $f(x)=\int_{x}^{x+1} \sin(e^t)dt$ then which of the following statements is/are correct

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, maxima-minima

Let $f(x)=\int_{x}^{x+1} \sin(e^t)dt$, then which of the following statements is/are correct

(a) $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx\leq 2$

(b) $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx\gt -e$

(c) $f(x)$ has local or global maxima at $x=\ln\bigg(\dfrac{\pi}{e+1}\bigg)$

(d) $f(x)$ is continuous

I've  got option (c) and (d) but I am not able to obtain (a) and (b)

This question was asked by one of my friend to me who is in 12th standard.

**Please Help me to proceed further and if possible provide full solution for (a) and (b)**

Comment: May help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497524/proving-that-an-int-infty-infty-int-kk1-sin-expxdxdk-integral-co?noredirect=1